# VSCode editor as git editor failed: Unable to connect to VSCode server

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using *VSCode* from *MacOS* connects via *SSH* to *centos server*.

When I run in VSCode termnial following:

```
git config --global -e
```

It shows:

```
Unable to connect to VS Code server.
Error in request
error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait'.
```

System:

```
   Static hostname: biomind <br />
         Icon name: computer-vm <br />
           Chassis: vm <br />
        Machine ID: 3d02d27c663b4a63ba96c077c010782d <br />
           Boot ID: 21fc1856408f48f181ed2bc6ca3b41af <br />
    Virtualization: vmware <br />   
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core) <br />
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7 <br />
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64 <br />
      Architecture: x86-64 <br />
```

Comment: I am having this issue but for WSL. DId you solve it at the end? Thank you in advance.